# NHibernate and AUTOFAC in WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, autofac

I'm looking for a good tutorial to configure AUTOFAC with NHibernate in a WinForm application injecting the ISession when a form is created and disposing the ISession on form close.

I found a lot of MVC and ASP.NET example but none using WinForm.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521813/nhibernate-winforms-castle-windsor-session-management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
public class FormFactory
{
    readonly ILifetimeScope scope;

    public FormFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public TForm CreateForm<TForm>() where TForm : Form
    {
        var formScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope("FormScope");
        var form = formScope.Resolve<TForm>();
        form.Closed += (s, e) => formScope.Dispose();
        return form;
    }
}
```

Register your `ISession` as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and Autofac will dispose of it when its scope is disposed. In this example, I am using the "FormScope" tag so that if I accidentally try to resolve an `ISession` out of another scope (maybe the top-level container scope) Autofac will throw an exception.

```
builder.Register(c => SomeSessionFactory.OpenSession())
    .As<ISession>()
    .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("FormScope");
```

Your code will have to commit the transaction explicitly (probably when the user clicks Save or something), and it probably should rollback the transaction if the user clicks Cancel. [Implicit rollback is not recommended.](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/AvoidImplicitRollback)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late and danyolgiax already found a solution.
Yesterday I was wondering how to combine Autofac with MVP in Winforms. I came into this [article](http://www.maciejaniserowicz.com/2010/04/28/model-view-presenter-z-autofac-w-aplikacji-desktopowej/).

It's written in Polish, so feel free to use a translator. The idea presented is very neat, clear and I'll certainly follow it when we'll migrate to Autofac with our project.
I thought it's worth keeping it here for people that should run into the same problem.