# Autofac & WinForms Integration Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac

I have a very simple WinForms POC utilizing Autofac and the MVP pattern.  In this POC, I am opening a child form from the parent form via Autofac's Resolve method.  What I'm having issues with is how the child form stays open.  In the `Display()` method of the child form, if I call `ShowDialog()` the child form remains open until I close it.  If I call `Show()`, the child form flashes and instantly closes - which is obviously not good.

I've done numerous searches for integrating Autofac into a WinForms application, however I've not found any good examples on Autofac/WinForms integration.

My questions are:

1. What is the proper way to display a non-modal child form with my approach?
2. Is there a better way to utilize Autofac in a WinForms application than my approach?
3. How do I determine there are no memory leaks and that Autofac is properly cleaning up the Model/View/Presenter objects for the child form?

Only relevant code is shown below.

Thanks,

Kyle

```
public class MainPresenter : IMainPresenter
{
    ILifetimeScope container = null;
    IView view = null;

    public MainPresenter(ILifetimeScope container, IMainView view)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.view = view;
        view.AddChild += new EventHandler(view_AddChild);
    }

    void view_AddChild(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Is this the correct way to display a form with Autofac?
        using(ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            scope.Resolve<ChildPresenter>().DisplayView(); //Display the child form
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of IPresenter

    public IView View
    {
        get { return view; }
    }

    public void DisplayView()
    {
        view.Display();
    }

    #endregion

}

public class ChildPresenter : IPresenter
{
    IView view = null;

    public ChildPresenter(IView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }

    #region Implementation of IPresenter

    public IView View
    {
        get { return view; }
    }

    public void DisplayView()
    {
        view.Display();
    }

    #endregion

}


public partial class ChildView : Form, IView
{
    public ChildView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Implementation of IView

    public void Display()
    {
        Show(); //<== BUG: Child form will only flash then instantly close.
        ShowDialog(); //Child form will display correctly, but since this call is modal, the parent form can't be accessed
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code:

```
using(ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    scope.Resolve<ChildPresenter>().DisplayView(); //Display the child form
}
```

First, it is good that you used a child lifetime scope. If you resolve out of the top-level container, the objects will live as long as that container (which is usually the whole lifetime of the application).

However, there is a problem here. When `DisplayView` calls `Form.Show`, it returns immediately. The `using` block ends, the child scope is disposed, and all of its objects (including the view) are also disposed.

In this case, you do not want a `using` statement. What you want to do is tie the child lifetime scope to the view so that when the view is closed, the child scope is disposed. See [the `FormFactory` in one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855283/644812) for an example. There are other ways you could adapt this idea to your architecture - you could do it in the registration (ContainerBuilder) for example.